# Permission denied to execute function

Tags: java, google-apps-script, google-api-java-client, google-apps-script-api

I am trying to run the code given below, where "myApp" is function Name in the Script which one I am trying to run.

```
ExecutionRequest request = new ExecutionRequest().setFunction("myApp").setDevMode(true);
try {
    Operation op = service.scripts().run("some id", request).execute();
    // Print results of request.
    if (op.getError() != null) {
        // The API executed, but the script returned an error.
        System.out.println("Error");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Success");
    }
} catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

Its giveing error me like:

> { "code" : 404, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" :
>   "Requested entity was not found.", "reason" : "notFound" } ],
>   "message" : "Requested entity was not found.", "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
>   }

or if I am deploying this as a web app it's giving this type of error:

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403
>   Forbidden { "code" : 403, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global",
>   "message" : "The caller does not have permission", "reason" :
>   "forbidden" } ], "message" : "The caller does not have permission",
>   "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED" }

What I have to do run the code perfectly????

Comment: Where are your authorization scopes?

Comment: Are the script and Java code using the same Google Platform project (as required)?

Comment: Hi @tehhowch 
Thanks for the reply,

I am passing previously them while authenticating

Comment: Please ensure you have completed the required steps: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute